# How-to just show order total on checkout page cart order summary

Tags: magento2, magento2.1.0

Looking for a solution that shows the order total in the cart order summary on the right side of the checkout page, without the product items. I have played around with altering checkout_index_index.xml but couldn't find a working solution. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can display the order total and also remove the products list by adding `checkout_index_index.xml` to your module/theme with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/subtotal</item>
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Cart Subtotal</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```