# How to show sub total section on checkout page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, totals

How to show sub-total section on Magento 2 checkout page sidebar?

Ex : [image]

I want to show this section on checkout page.
cart sub total section only visible on `www.example.com/checkout/#payment`

but I want to show it on `www.example.com/checkout/` page too.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130288/how-to-just-show-order-total-on-checkout-page-cart-order-summary